# Map having a class as key, allows for duplicate keys

Tags: c++, c++11, stdmap

I have a simple map program. It takes a class as a key. The class has multiple members. I assume my comparison function is correct. I am following the strict weak ordering. The problem is, it allows to enter duplicate keys.

Below is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <map>

class mapkey
{
public:
    std::string mInterface;
    std::string mDestination;
    int         mPrefixLen;
    std::string mNextHop;
    int         mMetric;

    mapkey() {}
   ~mapkey() {}
    mapkey(std::string a, std::string b, int c, std::string d, int e)
    {
      mInterface = a;
      mDestination = b;
      mPrefixLen = c;
      mNextHop = d;
      mMetric = e;
    }
};

struct mapcomp
{
  bool operator() (const mapkey left, const mapkey right);
};

bool mapcomp::operator() (const mapkey left, const mapkey right)
{
  if(strcmp(left.mInterface.c_str(), right.mInterface.c_str()) < 0)
    return true;
  if(strcmp(left.mInterface.c_str(), right.mInterface.c_str()) > 0)
    return false;

  if(strcmp(left.mDestination.c_str(), right.mDestination.c_str()) < 0)
    return true;
  if(strcmp(left.mDestination.c_str(), right.mDestination.c_str()) > 0)
    return false;

  if(strcmp(left.mNextHop.c_str(), right.mNextHop.c_str()) < 0)
    return true;
  if(strcmp(left.mNextHop.c_str(), right.mNextHop.c_str()) > 0)
    return false;

  if(left.mPrefixLen < right.mPrefixLen)
    return true;
  if(left.mPrefixLen > right.mPrefixLen)
    return false;

  if(left.mMetric < right.mMetric)
    return true;
  if(left.mMetric > right.mMetric)
    return false;
}

typedef std::map<mapkey, std::string, mapcomp> script_map;
script_map mm;

void print_map()
{
   script_map::const_iterator iter;
   for (iter = mm.begin(); iter != mm.end(); iter++)
   {
     std::cout << "value is - " << iter->second << std::endl;
   }
}

int main()
{
   mapkey test1("eth1", "50.60.70.80", 1, "90.10.20.30", 1);
   mm[test1] = "first";

   mapkey test2("eth1", "50.60.70.40", 1, "90.10.20.30", 1);
   mm[test2] = "second";

   mapkey test3("eth1", "50.60.70.20", 1, "90.10.20.30", 1);
   mm[test3] = "third";

   mapkey test4("eth1", "50.60.70.80", 1, "90.10.20.30", 1);
   mm[test4] = "fourth";

   print_map();

   return 0;
}
```

Above program, first and fourth key is same. when I print the map, the output is as below

g++ --std=c++11 map.cpp

./a.out

value is - third

value is - second

value is - fourth

value is - first

What am i missing ? The fourth entry should have not got added.

Comment: So, your comparison function is not correct.

Comment: What is with all of the C functions?  [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) comes with [built in comparison operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp).  You might also want to use [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie)

Comment: Your compiler should have warned you about the comparison possibly not returning a value, which happens if the objects are equal. If it did but you ignored it, stop ignoring warnings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The cause: your comparison function is broken.

The solution: write a new one using idiomatic C++.

```
struct mapcomp
{
  bool operator() (mapkey const& l, mapkey const& r) {
      return 
           std::tie(l.mInterface, l.mDestination, l.mPrefixLen, l.mNextHop, l.mMetric) 
           <
           std::tie(r.mInterface, r.mDestination, r.mPrefixLen, r.mNextHop, r.mMetric)
      ;
  }
};
```

- I pass `mapkey const&` instead of `mapkey` to avoid copying.
- I use tuple comparison and `std::tie` to make tuples out of your members.

Your should also delete all of the constructors and the destructor from the `mapkey`. They serve no purpose, given you can initialize the members by universal initialization.

I would also think about changing the struct to just an overload of `operator<` (and perhaps `operator==`) for your class. It will be enough for `map` to accept it without passing any other comparators.

Comment: They also might want to think about just switching over to a [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) as it has built in comparison functions for them.

Comment: @NathanOliver that might mean writing custom-named access tags. There are three strings and two ints, it would be easy to confuse.

Comment: Yeah it was just a suggestion.

Comment: Nice idea on using `std::tie`! It's the first time I see `std::tie` applied to map comparison function, and it fits very nice. Is it actually idiomatic?

Comment: @anatolyg I believe it is. I haven't invented it myself, but sadly I don't know whom to attribute the idea either.

Comment: Thank you so much Bartek for the solution and the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Begin from here:

```
if(strcmp(left.mInterface.c_str(), right.mInterface.c_str()) < 0)
    return true;
if(strcmp(left.mInterface.c_str(), right.mInterface.c_str()) > 0)
    return false;
```

`strcmp()` returns zero and only zero, when the strings are equal.

Then look at the first line: it returns `true` before all other members have a chance to be compared at all.

Comment: `std::string` provides `operator==()` why not use that instead of C's `strcmp()`?

Comment: `std::string` also provides `operator<()` and `operator>()`

Comment: @AlejandroDíaz, SimonKraemer: Essentially. I just think that the OP is, probably, a student – and then it's better to find more things on his own =)

Answer (score 0):

Your mapcomp method is not returning a value in all cases. You need a final return false at the end of your function to signal that the items are equal.

I suggest using the built-in string < operator and re-write your mapcomp method like this:

```
bool mapcomp::operator() (const mapkey& left, const mapkey& right)
{
  if(left.mInterface < right.mInterface) return true;
  if(left.mInterface > right.mInterface) return false;

  if(left.mDestination < right.mDestination) return true;
  if(left.mDestination > right.mDestination) return false;

  if(left.mNextHop < right.mNextHop) return true;
  if(left.mNextHop > right.mNextHop) return false;

  if(left.mPrefixLen < right.mPrefixLen) return true;
  if(left.mPrefixLen > right.mPrefixLen) return false;

  if(left.mMetric < right.mMetric) return true;
  if(left.mMetric > right.mMetric) return false;

  return false; // items are equal  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For C++ before you could use

```
bool mapcomp::operator() (const mapkey left, const mapkey right)
{
    if (left.mInterface != right.mInterface)        return left.mInterface < right.mInterface;
    if (left.mDestination != right.mDestination)    return left.mDestination < right.mDestination;
    if (left.mNextHop != right.mNextHop)            return left.mNextHop < right.mNextHop;
    if (left.mPrefixLen != right.mPrefixLen)        return left.mPrefixLen < right.mPrefixLen;
    if (left.mMetric != right.mMetric)              return left.mMetric < right.mMetric;
    return false; //equal != less
}
```